# Save SSE-Emitter object into MongoDB/Redis, Fetch it from Database and send event over it

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, redis

I am trying to make my REST API stateless. For that what I need is, to save client's SSE-Emitter object to mongo or redis so that it will be centrally accessible by other instances.

#### Current behavior:

I am able to save the SSE-emitter object to mongoDb but I think that object is being modified somehow because of which, after fetching it from mongoDb I am not able to send an event to client. If I save same emitter object in Map/List locally, the events are being sent out successfully.

#### Expected behaviour:

I should be able to fetch the emitter object from mongoDb and send EventData to client over it.

#### Source Code:

Controller where client subcribes:

```
@GetMapping("/memory/{userName}")
public SseEmitter handle(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
 SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
 try{
         MongoSession session = new MongoSession();
         session.setId(userName);
         session.setAttribute("emitter", emitter);
         mongoSessionRepo.save(session);
 }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
 }
 this.emitters.add(emitter);// adding it to list as well just for testing.
 emitter.onCompletion(() -> this.emitters.remove(emitter));
 emitter.onTimeout(() -> this.emitters.remove(emitter));

 return emitter;
}
```

MongoSession class which represents document in mongoDb:

```
package ch.rasc.sse;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.session.ExpiringSession;

@Document(collection = "springMongoSession")
public class MongoSession implements ExpiringSession{

  public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 1800;

  /**
  * MongoDB Object ID
  */
  @Indexed(unique = true)
  @Id
  private String id;

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  /**
  * Session ID
  */
  public static final String KEY_SESSION_ID = "_id";

  /**
   * Serialized session attributes
   */
  private byte[] serializedAttributes;

  /**
  * Session attributes (not saved to MongoDB)
   */
  private Map<String,Object> attributes;

/**
 * Creation time (epoch in ms)
 */
  private long creationTime;

/**
 * Last accessed time (epoch in ms)
 */
  private long lastAccessedTime;

/**
 * Max inactive interval (sec)
 */
  private int maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds;

/**
 * Expire time (epoch in ms)
 */
  @Indexed
  private long expireTime;
  public static final String KEY_EXPIRE_TIME = "expireTime";

/**
 * Constructor
 */
 public MongoSession() {
    attributes = new HashMap<>();
    creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    lastAccessedTime = creationTime;
    maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = DEFAULT_MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL_SECONDS;
    updateExpireTime();
 }

/**
 * Constructor
 */
 public MongoSession(String sessionId) {
    this.id = sessionId;
    //this.sessionId = sessionId;
    attributes = new HashMap<>();
    creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    lastAccessedTime = creationTime;
    maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = DEFAULT_MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL_SECONDS;
    updateExpireTime();
 }


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setLastAccessedTime(long lastAccessedTime) {
    this.lastAccessedTime = lastAccessedTime;
    updateExpireTime();
}


public long getCreationTime() {
    return creationTime;
}

public long getLastAccessedTime() {
    return lastAccessedTime;
}

public void setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(int interval) {
    maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = interval;
    updateExpireTime();
}

public int getMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds() {
    return maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds;
}

protected long getExpireTime() {
    return expireTime;
}

private void updateExpireTime() {
    expireTime = lastAccessedTime + maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds * 1000;
}

public boolean isExpired() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return expireTime <= now;
}

public <T> T getAttribute(String attributeName) {
    return (T)attributes.get(attributeName);
}

public Set<String> getAttributeNames() {
    return attributes.keySet();
}

public void setAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue) {

   attributes.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
}

public void removeAttribute(String attributeName) {
    attributes.remove(attributeName);
}
/**
 * Serialize session attributes
 */
 public void serializeAttributes() {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
        oos.writeObject(attributes);
        oos.flush();
        serializedAttributes = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        serializedAttributes = new byte[0];
    }
}
public void serializeAttributesThis(Object attributeValue) {
   try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
       oos.writeObject(attributeValue);
       oos.flush();
       serializedAttributes = bos.toByteArray();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       //e.printStackTrace();
       serializedAttributes = new byte[0];
   }
 }
   /**
   * Deserialize session attributes
   */
  public void deserializeAttributes() {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedAttributes);
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis))  {
        attributes = (Map<String,Object>)ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        attributes = new HashMap<>();
    }
  }
 }
```

On below request I want to send eventData back to client:

```
    @RequestMapping("/qmevents/{sessionId}")
    public void readQmEvents(@PathVariable("sessionId") String userName)
    {
       try{
        System.out.println("Emitter Object: 
         "+mongoSessionRepo._getSession(userName));
        System.out.println("Emitter Object: 
  "+mongoSessionRepo._getSession(userName).getAttributeNames());
        System.out.println("Emitter Object: 
  "+mongoSessionRepo._getSession(userName)
    .getAttribute("emitter").toString());
    sessionRepo.getSessionAttributes(userName, "emitter");
    SseEmitter emitter =mongoSessionRepo._getSession(userName).
            getAttribute("emitter");
    MemoryMXBean memBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
    MemoryUsage heap = memBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
    MemoryUsage nonHeap = memBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage();
    MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo(heap.getUsed(), nonHeap.getUsed());
        mi.setForUserName("Event raised by QM");
        System.out.println("Emitter from map: 
     "+SSEControllerPerUser.emitters.get(0));
        SSEControllerPerUser.emitters.get(0).send(mi);
        //emitter.send(mi);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to persist the connections, the connections usually remain open between 15 and 30 seconds, when the "Timeout" event occurs you must delete the object "SSEEmitter" from the dictionary in memory and the client must start a new connection.

Comment: We wanted it when server crashes and Secondary Server goes Up in that case. Anyway thanks for your thoughts :)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the Spring SseEmitter(refer below) and use that component, I have used this solution for the similar scenario that you have described(server crash).

```
public class SerializableSSE extends SseEmitter implements Serializable{

    public SerializableSSE() {
    }

    public SerializableSSE(Long timeout) {
        super(timeout);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting... Did you actually test that it works? My understanding is that in case of SSE, Tomcat (or whatever app server you happen to use) keeps the http connection alive for the entire duration of the session. If the server crashes the connection is gone. Even if you restore the SseEmitter object, the connection is already gone. In the classic client-server scenario server is not able to establish a new connection, only client can do that.

Comment: I am converting SerializableSSE object to byte[] to store in SQL db
but when I look into DB, or any new connection after converting it to byte[], all emitter requests has same byte[]

2nd issue, and after creating SerializableSSE object if I return directly or typecasting to SseEmitter  (no byte[] operation), its not working
but creating SseEmitter object & sending works

Any idea for these issues?